# Trying to get rid of the commas attached to the elements in my nested list

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, nested-lists

The contents of my file look like this when read from the file (which DOES include commas):

dog cat bird fog 100

animal wolf lion pterodactyl 200

more arbitrary animals 300

In my code I include every attempt I've made at this. Some produce a result where each individual character becomes a new string, so like [['t'],['h'],['i'],['s']], most of them however produce:

```
[['dog,','cat,','bird,','fog,','100']]
```

....and so on

This is my issue. The comma in the string.

**MY ATTEMPTS:**

```
data = open("words.txt", "r")   
file_contents = data.read()
data = file_contents.replace(',','') #gets rid of commas
print(data)

print('\n\n')

#1:
file=open("words.txt","r")
lineList=[]
for line in file:
    words=line.split(" ")
    lineList.append(words)
print(lineList)

#2:
file=open("words.txt","r").read().replace(',',' ')
lineList=[line.split() for line in file]
print(lineList)

#3:
with open("words.txt") as file_contents:
    lineList = file_contents.read().replace(',','   ')
print(lineList)

#4:
file=open("words.txt","r")
lineList=[line.split() for line in file]
print(lineList)

#5:
file=open("words.txt","r")
lineList=[line.split() for line in file]
print(lineList)

#6:
for i, elem in enumerate(lineList):
    if elem == ',':
        elem[i] = ' '
print(lineList)
```

What it looks like now:

```
[['dog,','cat,','bird,','fog,','100'],['animal,','wolf,','lion,','pterodactyl,','200'],['more,','arbitrary,','animals,'300]]
```

I want the end result to look like this:

```
[['dog','cat','bird','fog','100'],['animal','wolf','lion','pterodactyl','200'],['more','arbitrary','animals','300']]
```

Any ideas? Thanks!!

Comment: The example of the file's content doesn't have any commas but you say that it does. Please edit to show the actual contents.

Comment: Have you tried using the cab module?

Answer (score 0):

Attempt #4 seems pretty close - try splitting by both a space and a comma:

```
file=open("words.txt","r")
lineList=[line.split(" ,") for line in file]
print(lineList)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can go element by element using split funcion.

For example:

```
my_list = ["cat,","dog","horse,"]
my_newList = []
for i in my_list:
        my_newList.append(i.split(",")[0])

print(my_newList)
```

> ['cat','dog','horse']

Comment: Thank you so much! That does work, only issue being at the end of every nested list the last element has a \n attached to it like this:

Comment: `my_newList[-1] = my_newList[-1].split("\n")[0]` , index[-1] get last element of the list and updates removing '\n' by using split function. Please check if it works!